# Можете пожалуйста обьяснить как работает функция fit. А точнее модете обьяснить что делают тут функции np.zeros, shape, .T

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

```py
# Описание класса перцептрон
class Perceptron(object):
    
    def __init__(self, eta = 0.01, n_iter = 10):
        self.eta = eta #Темп обучения (от 0 до 1)

        self.n_iter = n_iter #Количество итераций(уроков)
        """
        Выполнить подгонку модели под тренировочные данные.

        Параметры
        X-тренировочные данные: массив, размерность - X[n_samples, n_features],
        где

        n_samples - число образцов
        n_iter - число признаков

        y - Целевые значения: массив, размерность - y[n_samples]
        self:object
        """

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.w_ = np.zeros(1 + X.shape[1]) # W_ : одномерный массив - веса после обучения

        self.errors_ = []  #Список ошибок классификации в каждой эпохе

        for _ in range(self.n_iter):
            errors = 0
            for xi, target in zip(X, y):
                update = self.eta * (target - self.predict(xi))
                self.w_[1:] += update * xi
                self.w_[0] += update
                errors += int(update != 0.0)

            self.errors_.append(errors)
        return self
        
    """Рассчитать чистый код"""
    def net_input(self, X):
        return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]
        
    """Вернуть метку класса после единичного скачка"""

    def predict(self, X):
        return np.where(self.net_input(X) >= 0.0, 1, -1)
```

Comment: [np.zeros](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) (Возвращает матрицу/массив заполненный нулями) [shape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html) (возвращает размер матрицы/массива) и [.T](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) (Транспонирует оси)

Comment: Но вообще это всё есть в документации по Numpy. Документацию полезно читать.